# Arch Linux boot errors

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I am installing Linux Arch on old windows xp notebook,all time when I start booting it show these errors and booting isn't continuing.

What is wrong?, and how do I fix it?

[image: Error Page]

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors!](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: Post the contents of `/etc/fstab` and the output of `lsblk`, please.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear if you're trying to boot the flash drive to begin installation, or if you already installed and is trying to boot the installed system.

Either way, the problem is that it is trying to boot looking for a disk with name ARCH_201901, which to by coincidence, is the name of the arch Linux installation media.

If you're trying to boot the flash drive to begin installation, you probably had problems preparing the flash drive, and this might be a duplicate of [question on super user](https://superuser.com/questions/519784/error-installing-arch-linux).

If you already installed(I don't think that's the case?) you did something incorrect on your installation, repeat the process carefully, specially the part on mounting partitions and `arch-chroot`ing.